# sequelize: Inserting recordsets in one go instead of looping them

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am new using sequelize in node.js.

I have a recordsets which I am inserting record by record using .create().

I think there must be a more straightforward way to insert them in one go instead of now I am looping them in sequelize.

This is what I am doing now:

```
var myProcessTableSchema = {
    Profile_UUID: {type:Sequelize.STRING(36), allowNull: false, primaryKey: true},
    ItemNmbr: {type:Sequelize.STRING(15), allowNull: true},
    UnitPrice: {type:Sequelize.DECIMAL(10,2), allowNull: true},
    ItemDesc: {type:Sequelize.STRING(512), allowNull: true},
};

var myProcessTableSchemaIndex = {
    indexes: [
        {
            name:'myProcess_profile',
            unique:false,
            fields:['Profile_UUID']
        }
    ],
    freezeTableName:true
};  

var myProcessTable = db.seqConnection.define(processingName, myProcessTableSchema, myProcessTableSchemaIndex);
myProcessTable.sync({force: true, freezeTableName: true, createdAt: false, updatedAt: false}).then(function(){

        for (k = 0; k < recordsets[0].length; k++)
        {
            var logData = {
                    Profile_UUID: recordsets[0][k].Profile_UUID,
                    ItemNmbr: recordsets[0][k].ItemNmbr,
                    UnitPrice: recordsets[0][k].UnitPrice,
                    ItemDesc: recordsets[0][k].ItemDesc
            };              

            myProcessTable.create(logData).then(function(){
                console.log('Inserted.');
            }).catch(function(err){
                    console.log("MYSQL Create Processing Table Error : " + err.message);    
            });
        }

        console.log('After loop....');
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `Model.bulkCreate()` which accepts array of objects and insert them into DB

```
User.bulkCreate([
    { username: 'barfooz', isAdmin: true },
    { username: 'foo', isAdmin: true },
    { username: 'bar', isAdmin: false }
])
```

Here's docs http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/instances/#working-in-bulk-creating-updating-and-destroying-multiple-rows-at-once